# The most powerful between a flutter button and a homemade button

Tags: performance, flutter, dart, button, flutter-layout

I wanted to know which is the most powerful between a flutter button and a homemade button and the inconvenience of a homemade button?

For exemple, flutter buttons: `ElevatedButton`, `TextButton`, `OutlinedButton`

And an exemple of a homemade button:

```
Container(
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {},
    child: Text('click'),
  ),
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by more powerful?

Comment: As with everything, implementing things yourself will be the most work but will give you the most freedom.  Whether you should make that trade-off is something only *you* can decide.  In general, you should prefer existing solutions unless you have some clear reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

You should decide to use a button depending on the type of work you want to do

onstream `Gesture Detector` has a lot property for each type of touch and press and `Text Button` `Icon Button` `Outlined Button` `Elevated Button` and other provided buttons not has a lot touch property  BUT has somw animation and simple to use for new comers in flutter